# How to use non static method in activity extends application in MainActivity extends activity

Tags: android

I am developer and i need help I use method non static in class G when extends application I want use method non static in activity how to cast non static to static for use method in activity extend activity.

Comment: Have you tried to use Interface instead. Both Application SubClass and Activity Class can implement the interface Method to communicate?

Comment: A diagram or a clearer explanation would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: no please help me if useful.

Comment: Please show example code that demonstrates the problem and be clear about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a static method that create an instance of the activity and call the non static method for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing called casting non static to static 
if you mean calling non-static method in static method, then you simply have to  create an instance of the class you want to call the method on.

**For Example:**

```
new Class().nonStaticMethod();
```